# How To print Space Between Control Creation at Run Time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating `Label` controls at runtime in a loop but there is no space between them.

How would I put some space in between? My code is:

```
  for (int m = 0; m < dtGroupedByDate.Rows.Count; m++)
  {
      Label Date = new Label();
      Date.Text = dtGroupedByDate.Rows[m][0].ToString();
      this.Controls.Add(Date);
      Label PowerSum = new Label();
      PowerSum.Text = dtGroupedByDate.Rows[m][1].ToString();
      this.Controls.Add(PowerSum);                       
  }
```

Hope for your reply!

Comment: sorry for inconvinent i try but cant show my code properly please copy paste it in a note pad

Comment: I've formatted your code for you - you can use the 'format code' button in the editor toolbar to do blocks of code. Just highlight what you want to format and click the two curly braces: `{}`.

Comment: @Town: Wow. I was editing at the same time and SO detected that it could merge my changes into yours (I did the *exact* same formatting), so it automagically merged without complaining. Impressed.

Comment: which technology, asp.net, windows forms ?

Comment: @TOwn thanks for your help and i am using asp.net i am creating label at run time how would i create space also between the controlls??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;"));
```

this line goes between those two adds

Comment: thanks and if i also want a new lne before controll creation then ?

Comment: this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

Comment: @Syed Raza, Yeah, I agree with @Adrian, you can write any html code you want inside the `LiteralControl` for making spacing between controls added dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using CSS.

I don't know the format of your document, but a `Label` control in ASP.NET renders either as a `span` or, if `AssociatedControlID` is set, a `label`.  So, at a basic level something like:

```
span, label { margin-right: 10px; }
```

This would change *all* spans and labels, so if possible you should constrain it by specifying the container in the selector.

Comment: @Syed Raza: That goes in your CSS file or in the `head` of your page within a `style` tag.

Comment: Actually i have these values in a data table is there any other alternate to print these vales as i have to show these values in a ms chart but i havnt found any graph option so i am trying to print it in a label...

Comment: Label control renders as a <span> when there is no associated control set(ie AssociatedControlID is not set), otherwise it's rendered as a <label>

Comment: @Syed Raza: I don't know about MS Chart, but if for some reason you can't use CSS to do your layout then adding a `LiteralControl` as per Adrian's answer would solve your problem.

Comment: IMO, I would go for this solution, but I should be aware that ALL spans and labels would have this style.

Comment: @Adrian Iftode: True enough, without knowing the format of the HTML it's hard to specify a more controlled rule though.

Comment: @Syed Raza: If you need an introduction to CSS then this could be a good place to start: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Guide/Style.

Answer (score 1):

Use positioning

```
for (int m = 0; m < dtGroupedByDate.Rows.Count; m++)
{
   Label Date = new Label();
   Date.Text = dtGroupedByDate.Rows[m][0].ToString();
   Date.Style["margin-left"] = (m > 0) ? "20px" : "0px";
   this.Controls.Add(Date);
   Label PowerSum = new Label();
   PowerSum.Text = dtGroupedByDate.Rows[m][1].ToString();
   PowerSum.Style["margin-left"] = "20px";
   this.Controls.Add(PowerSum);
}
```

this answers ur question. however for a better formatting,  in a case u dont want to display all ur labels in a single row,  use `style["margin-top"]`. the final outcome depends on the positioning u are using (i.e. "absolute", "relative",...). so first thing i suggest is read a bit more about positioning.

Comment: i am willing to mark up your answer but my reputation is less then 15 so i cant mark up your answer hopes you dont mind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim fnt As New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point)
        Dim i, x, y As Integer
        x = 30
        y = 25
        i = 0
        For i = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim chk As New CheckBox()
            chk.Text = dt1.Rows(i)(0)
            chk.Location = New Point(x, y)
            chk.Font = fnt
            chk.Width = 450
            chk.ForeColor = Color.White

            Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(chk)
```

hope you will convert it into c# :)
I have use this code recently

Comment: that code will work only if ur project is winform. `asp.net checkbox` has no `Location` property.